# Java LastDigitDistribution

Tags: java

There is a problem in my Java textbook that has me quite baffled. In this problem I am supposed to implement a Sequence class to a SquaredSequence class and various other classes that share a next() method. The next() method is supposed to return an int that is then processed by a LastDigitDistribution class. In the book the values that are supposed to return once the program is run are given, however I cannot figure out how those values came to be. I was wondering if someone could explain it to me?

```
public class LastDigitDistribution
{
   private int[] counters;

   /**
      Constructs a distribution whose counters are set to zero.
   */
   public LastDigitDistribution()
   {
      counters = new int[10];
   }

   /**
      Processes values from this sequence.
      @param seq the sequence from which to obtain the values
      @param valuesToProcess the number of values to process
   */
   public void process(Sequence seq, int valuesToProcess)
   {
      for (int i = 1; i <= valuesToProcess; i++)
      {
         int value = seq.next();
         int lastDigit = value % 10;
         counters[lastDigit]++;
      }
   }

   /**
      Displays the counter values of this distribution.
   */
   public void display()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println(i + ": " + counters[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the class that implements the Sequence interface

```
  public class SquareSequence implements Sequence
  {
    private int n;

    public int next()
   {
         n++;
        return n * n; 
    }
   }
```

Here is the tester class

```
 public class SequenceDemo
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     LastDigitDistribution dist1 = new LastDigitDistribution();
     dist1.process(new SquareSequence(), 1000);
     dist1.display();
     System.out.println();
   }
```

Console values:

0: 100

1: 200

2: 0

3: 0

4: 200

5: 100

6: 200

7: 0

8: 0

9: 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot figure out how those values came to be.

The class counts the number of occurrences of the last digits. For example, given the sequence of squared numbers from 1 to 10:

- 1: 2, the square of 1 and 9 has last digit 1
- 4: 2, the square of 2 and 8 has last digit 4
- ... and so on

In the case of the sequence for 1 to 1000,
apparently there are 100 squared numbers that end in 0, 200 that end in 1, and so on.

The program uses the modulo operator to get the last digit of the number:

```
int lastDigit = value % 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

The next method in Square sequence is working as shown below

First Iteration

int n = 0
then
n++ is n = 1

return n*n = 1*1 = 1

value = 1

lastDigit = 1 % 10 = 1

counters[1]++ = counters[1] = 1

value from the next method would be 1*1, 2*2, 3*3, 4*4, ... and so on

and the reason for the values of the counter[] are as follows

Square series always ends with digits 0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9 example 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, ....

So there will be values in the counter array for elements counter[0], counter[1], counter[4] , counter[5], counter[6] and counter[9].

The values in this array denotes the count of the square numbers ending with the respective digits(lastdigit = squarevalue%10)

**This is how the value is arrived**

10*10, 20*20, 30*30, ........, 990*990, 1000*1000, for each square ending with 0 we are adding the counter[0]++ and hence counter[0] = 100 ,

None of the square ends with digits 2, 3, 7 and 8 and hence there will be no 
values for counter[2], counter[3], counter[7], counter[8]